# Opening XML file in a new thread?

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, filestream

Hi I'm Having some trouble, i was wonder how to read an XML file in a new thread heres basically what I'm trying to do:

```
//This is ran when the user presses the Enter Key
Thread LoadThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test));
LoadThread.Start();

private static void Test()
{
    FileStream stream = File.Open("TEST_1.xml", FileMode.Open);
    //----
    //  Code Using File (I know this stuff works)
    //----
    stream.Close();
}
```

Here's the Error.

Directory\TEST_1.xml' because it is being used by another process.

But when its not a thread of its own it works fine ?

Thanks for the help, if this can't be done like this, how can i open the file without it making my program Freeze until the file has been opened ?

thanks again.

Comment: Have you used process explorer to see what has the file locked when you're trying to read it?

Comment: @Dusy - try to open that file in non-thread method and see what happen?

Comment: Put `try` `catch` block and close stream in  `finally` block. `finally { stream.Close(); }` Also try `stream.Flush();` & `stream.Dispose();` Does this helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your sample code and did not run into any problems. I did, however, get the same exception when I pressed the enter key while the file was being read. (i.e. pressed the enter key twice) Is it possible you have two handlers for the Enter key, which are both triggering this file to be opened. Can you place a breakpoint on the File.Open statement and see how many times it is hit before the exception occurs.

Comment: WOW, thank you, can't believe it was so simple :) i can finally continue and get other things done

Comment: Glad to hear its fixed, good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code or a process that is writing to the file?  If so, you'll need to do some locking:

```
private static object _fileLock = new object();

private static void Test()
{
    lock(_fileLock)
    {
        using(FileStream stream = File.Open("TEST_1.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            //Stuff you know works
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried using your code, says _fileLock does not exist in its current context, I'm still quite new to things like this, thanks for helping or is there something I'm Missing ?

Comment: Did you declare _fileLock in the same class that Test() is declared?

Comment: Did you make Void void? It seems RQDQ messed up with his capitols.

Comment: yes, its right above it, like in your code. also Void was already void, Void gives me :System.Void cannot be used from C# -- use typeof(void) to get the void type object

Comment: I updated the cases to be correct / match for void and _fileLock

Comment: alright i got the filelock to work but now, it doesn't give me an error but it also doesn't open the file (think its just skipping over because the file is in use... maybe ?) I've gone over the rest of my code and i don't see anywhere in which the file is used?

Comment: yep there is no other point that the file gets used other than that one line? i have no idea why its not working when i throw it in a thread of its own

Comment: How many times is this function being called?  Have you put a breakpoint at the start of Test() to see if the method is being called more than once?